# How to use background image in custom class defined in tailwind config on next.js project

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Trying to use an image on a custom class that is defined in `tailwind.config.ts` file. The project is Next.js (13.5) project.
Following is the project structure

```
project_dir
|    src
|    |    app
|    |    |    globals.css // tailwind configured here
|    |    |    ...
|    |    assets
|    |    |    demo
|    |    |    |    images
|    |    |    |    |    ... // images are here
|    |
|    tailwind.config.ts
|    ...
```

```js
// tailwind.config.ts
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss';

const config: Config = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'hero': "url('../assets/demo/images/bg1.svg')",
        'card': "url('../assets/demo/images/bg2.svg')",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
};
export default config;
```

This produces url that doesnt work (tested on chrome & firefox). Following is the generated class

```css
.bg-card {
    background-image: url(webpack:///mini-css-extract-plugin//_next/static/media/bg1.29d36fbf.svg);
}
```

Error on chrome

```
GET webpack:///mini-css-extract-plugin//_next/static/media/bg1.189c279d.svg net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

What is the ideal solution could be considering the project structure?